# How can I add jQuery elements to an existing jquery variable

Tags: jquery, arrays

I want to add jQuery elements to a jQuery variable. Here's an example of a table; when I click in a cell containing BBBB, I want to toggle the highlight of all the BBBB headers. **Using the .add() method inside an $.each iteration does not seem to work**, it results in an empty element. (The example below now works)

```
<script>
$( function () {
$( "td" ).click(function() {
var index = $(this).prevAll().length;  
var $table = $(this).parent().parent().parent()
var id=$table.find('tr').first().find(':nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').attr('id')
var $ret=$()
$headers = $("table").find('#' + id)
$.each(
    $headers, 
    function (index, value) { $ret=$ret.add(value); } 
    )
$ret.toggleClass('highlight')
 })
})
</script>

<table id="t1">
<thead><tr><th id="a">AAAA</th><th id="c">CCCC</th><th id="d">DDDD</th> 
</tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>AAAA</td><td>CCCC</td><td>DDDD</td></tr>
<tr><td>AAAA</td><td>CCCC</td><td>DDDD</td></tr>
<tr><td>AAAA</td><td>CCCC</td><td>DDDD</td></tr>
<tr><td>AAAA</td><td>CCCC</td><td>DDDD</td></tr>
<tr><td>AAAA</td><td>CCCC</td><td>DDDD</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>
<table id="t2">
<thead><tr><th id="b">BBBB</th><th id="c">CCCC</th><th id="d">DDDD</th>    </tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>BBBB</td><td>CCCC</td><td>DDDD</td></tr>
<tr><td>BBBB</td><td>CCCC</td><td>DDDD</td></tr>
<tr><td>BBBB</td><td>CCCC</td><td>DDDD</td></tr>
<tr><td>BBBB</td><td>CCCC</td><td>DDDD</td></tr>
<tr><td>BBBB</td><td>CCCC</td><td>DDDD</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>
<table id="t3">
<thead><tr><th id="a">AAAA</th><th id="b">BBBB</th><th id="c">CCCC</th><th id="d">DDDD</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>AAAA</td><td>BBBB</td><td>CCCC</td><td>DDDD</td></tr>
<tr><td>AAAA</td><td>BBBB</td><td>CCCC</td><td>DDDD</td></tr>
<tr><td>AAAA</td><td>BBBB</td><td>CCCC</td><td>DDDD</td></tr>
<tr><td>AAAA</td><td>BBBB</td><td>CCCC</td><td>DDDD</td></tr>
<tr><td>AAAA</td><td>BBBB</td><td>CCCC</td><td>DDDD</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Show us your JS code.

Comment: Duplicating `ID` is a very very common/danger **error**

Comment: good point, I'll switch to classes

Comment: You ask about a jquery array, yet show us no jquery or js.  Please create a [mcve] with your current code demonstrating the problem you have

Comment: tried changing id for class. Curiously, the first click of the toggle works (+highlight), but not the second (-highlight)! I'll switch back to id, since that seems to work

Comment: Hi @Pete , I've posted the jQuery in the answer below. I read it was encouraged to answer one's own questions. Was I wrong?

Comment: I was more on about the question, you can answer your own questions as much as you want but how do you expect anyone else to help you with your code when you don't show it.  By using an id, your code will only work on the first one of that id it comes to - duplicate ids are invalid and will lead to "errors" with how you expect things to work

Comment: @pete I added the jquery to the code of the question. On the point of the id vs classes, the toggle only works with id, not with class (tested on Firefox and Chrome). With class the add class works, not the remove class. However much it "should" work better with classes, that was what I observed.

Comment: Just trying to point out, see if your code works on table 2 as well as table 1, my bet is it doesn't.  But hey if you want to carry on with invalid code just because it "works" then be my guest

Comment: @pete I'd willingly change for valid code if it behaved as expected.

Answer (score 0):

After messing around quite a bit, I arrived at this syntax, that works.

```
<script>
$( function () {
$( "td" ).click(function() {
var index = $(this).prevAll().length;  
var $table = $(this).parent().parent().parent()
var id=$table.find('tr').first().find(':nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').attr('id')
var $ret=$()
$headers = $("table").find('#' + id)
$.each(
    $headers, 
    function (index, value) { $ret=$ret.add(value); } 
    )
$ret.toggleClass('highlight')
 })
})
</script>
```

The secret is in https://api.jquery.com/add , which reads:

> The following will not save the added elements, because the .add() method creates a new set and leaves the original set in pdiv unchanged:

```
var pdiv = $( "p" );
pdiv.add( "div" ); // WRONG, pdiv will not change
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-assign a variable when using `add()`.

```
var td = $();
$('table').on('click', 'td', function(){
    td = td.add($(this));
});
```